# How to write below dots in latex

Tags: math-mode, arrows

> How to write the following in latex:
>   (q-p,-1,-1(q-1)...... times ,-1,1,1,......(p-1) times 1)

I have a vector which consists of the first term to be q-p.
Then we have -1 as the corresponding terms and it goes upto q-1 times and then we have 1 as the corresponding terms which goes upto p-1 times.

How to write the above vector by writing q-1 below the dots for -1 and p-1 below the dots for 1?

Any help will be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    ( q-p,\underbrace{ -1, \dotsc, -1 }_{q-1 \text{ times}},\underbrace{1 , \dotsc , 1 }_{p-1\text{ times}} )
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]